# Associated Legendre polynomials in Mathematica

Tags: special-functions, polynomials

I'm trying to look at the Associated Legendre Polynomial, so I plugged it into Mathematica to see the values for different input.

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associated_Legendre_polynomials):

$$
p_l(x)=\frac{1}{2^l l!}\frac{\partial ^l}{\partial x^l}\left(x^2-1\right)^l
$$

$$
p_l^m(x) = (-1)^m(1-x^2)^{m/2}\frac{\partial ^l}{\partial x^l}p_l(x)
$$

But when I try to program this in Mathematica, I get a strange behavior (I think)

```
p[x_, l_, m_] = (-1)^m*(1 - x^2)^(m/2)*
   D[1/(2^l l!)*D[(x^2 - 1)^l, {x, l}], {x, m}];
```

Above, what I think is the correct Associated Legendre Polynomial is zero for any value of m not equal to zero. Why?

I looked at just $p_l(x)$:

```
pl[x_, l_] = 1 / (2^l * l!) * D[(x^2 - 1)^l, {x, l}];
D[pl[2, 3], {x, m}]
```

When I took the derivative of $p_l(x)$ at $x=2, L = 3$
$$
\begin{array}{cc}
 \{ & 
\begin{array}{cc}
 17 & m=0 \\
 0 & \text{True} \\
\end{array}
 \\
\end{array}
$$

This shows that it is zero for any value of $m \neq 0$. Is my code or the equation I am using wrong? Or should the derivative really be zero for any m?

Comment: This is late, but it should be noted that `LegendreP[]` is built-in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are evaluating the intermediate results too soon. Consider this simple example:

$$f_\ell(x) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} x^\ell.$$

What is $f_3(2)$? To evaluate this, you first do the differentiation and then apply the $x$:

$$f_3(2) = \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x} x^3\right)\bigg|_{x=2} = 3x^2\big|_{x=2} = 12.$$

You cannot do it like this:

$$f_2(3) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} 3^2 = 0 \quad (?!)$$

But this is exactly what you do in the second code:

```
D[pl[2, 3], {x, m}]
```

First, `pl[2, 3]` is evaluated to a constant ($17$), whose derivative is then obviously zero.

One way to resolve this is to use a differently named "dummy" variable for differentiation:

```
pl[x_, l_] := 1/(2^l*l!)*D[(x^2 - 1)^l, {x, l}];
p[x_, l_, m_] := (-1)^m*(1 - x^2)^(m/2)*D[pl[y, l], {y, m}] /. y -> x;

p[x, 2, 1]
(* -3 x Sqrt[1-x^2] *)

p[1/2, 3, 1]
(* -((3 Sqrt[3])/16) *)

p[.2, 2, 2]
(* 2.88 *)
```

When plotting, don't forget to use `Evaluate`, otherwise $P_m^l$ will be unnecessarily recalculated for each plot point.

```
GraphicsGrid[Partition[
  Table[Plot[
    Evaluate[Table[LegendreP[l, m, x], {m, 0, l}]], {x, -1, 1}, 
    PlotLegends -> Table[Subsuperscript["P", l, m], {m, 0, l}]], {l, 
    0, 3}], 2], ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I think I got it as: 
```
pl[x_, l_] = 1/(2^l*l!)*D[(x^2 - 1)^l, {x, l}];
p[x_, l_, m_] = (-1)^m*(1 - x^2)^(m/2)*D[pl[x, l], {x, m}];
p[x, 3, 1];
```

But how to evaluate at say, x=2?

Comment: To evaluate the derivative at a point, you can use ``Replace``: ``D[x^3, x] /. x -> 2 (* 12 *)``.

Comment: When I substitute after p[x,3,1] /. x -> 1/2 it works. But when I substitute in the equation it fails (General::ivar: 1/2 is not a valid variable.) Edit: It worked when I put the whole equation in parenthesis.